# Convert Outlook REST API item id to MAPI EntryID

Tags: json, rest, outlook, exchange-server, mapi

is there an officially supported way to convert item ids from the Outlook `REST` API into an `MAPI` EntryID?

I am talking about the "Id" field returned for items in the json response of an http `GET` on a mailbox endpoint like so:

https://outlook.office365.com/api/v2.0/me/messages

The Id field contains a base64 value. When I convert it to hex and compare it to the `PR_ENTRY_ID` value of the same item, e.g. with `MFCMAPI`, I can find the EntryID is contained in the hex version of the Id field.

Is there an official documentation how to convert between the id formats?

Or an API to call? Would prefer a local convert functions to avoid additional `REST` roundtrips.

Thanks for any hints
SvenC

Answer (score 8):

Your query to the Microsoft Graph API can specify that you would like to include the `PR_ENTRYID` or other MAPI properties. Here is the [official documentation](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/resources/extended-properties-overview) for `singleValueLegacyExtendedProperty` from Microsoft.

For example, if you wanted to fetch a page of your messages and include the `PR_ENTRYID`, you could make a `GET` request to:

`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages?$expand=singleValueExtendedProperties($filter=id%20eq%20'Binary%200x0FFF')`

Without URL encoding, the `$expand` statement reads: 
`$expand=singleValueExtendedProperties($filter=id eq 'Binary 0x0FFF')`

There are three valid syntaxes to filter for MAPI properties:

1. `'MapiPropertyType namespaceGuid Name propertyName'`
2. `'MapiPropertyType namespaceGuid Id propertyId'`
3. `'MapiPropertyType propertyTag'`

Note that the example above uses #3, and that 0x0FFF is the `propertyTag` for `PR_ENTRYID` per the [[MS-OXPROPS] Exchange Server Protocols Master Property List](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc433490%28v=exchg.80%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

> is there an officially supported way to convert item ids from the Outlook REST API into an MAPI EntryID?

No, office.js API doesn't have anything to convert REST/EWS Id to PR_ENTRY_ID

> Is there an official documentation how to convert between the id formats?

Obviously there is no documentation as of point above

> Or an API to call? Would prefer a local convert functions to avoid additional REST roundtrips.

Yes, there are calls to retrieve (not convert) IMessage Id and this is exactly what you've done ... RESTful or EWS requests. With those requests you are able to get IMessage properties, including PR_ENTRY_ID. I just don't really understand what you are going to use it for? Any requests back to the message have to be done with EWS/REST Id anyway. Well, probably this is something to do with your message manipulation.

Comment: I see. Well, there is nothing for you, other than request it with EWS or REST and after send it to your service. Actually I meet the first time someone who use this approach. Would you mind to tell me what kind of work does your service? Of cause, if it's not business secret. I guess it looking for some property in the message set by add-in and do something to this message based on it? Also is it reliable and work for every single message? Do you have any hiccups for this service? I will be very appreciated.

Comment: The context is a Mail App which (roughly) sends the EntryID as email-body into a monitored server mailbox. A MAPI based service gets that EntryID and processes the item. With EWS we get MAPI properties by proptag. Could not find that for REST but the Id value looks almost usable. Do you have details to get PR_ENTRY_ID by REST? I found a promising syntax using query param $expand [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/api/mail-rest-operations). Seems missing in Exchange 2016 On-Prem (latest CU4 from dec 2016 installed) which responds to v2.0 REST calls.

Comment: Sorry - pressed <enter> in hope for a line break and sent an incomplete comment - deleted and readded the comment. Maybe Ex2016 On-Prem REST API does less than Office365

Comment: Our service reads the message content, puts it into another storage system and marks the item as processed. Works reliable - only hickup is when a user of our  Mail App executes the App command and immediately moves or deletes the item which renders the EntryID. Not a typical user action for our customers.

Comment: "Do you have details to get PR_ENTRY_ID by REST?". Unfortunately I am not an expert with REST as our app uses EWS for communication and I just payed a bit with REST against our O365. But you are on the right track, as I saw many times ppl are using "$expand=SingleValueExtendedProperties" to get extended message props. The only thing as you mention is availability for Exchange on prem. Sorry, no help over here. Thanks for info, you provided ;)