# Is it possible to filter email using EntryID (PR_ENTRYID) with Outlook REST API?

Tags: office365api, outlook-restapi

We are currently using EWS Managed APIs in our application and looking to migrate to use Outlook REST API approach. I am new to Outlook REST API world and looking for some inputs.

I am trying to fetch email from exchange using PR_ENTRYID with REST API and retrieve its properties, however always facing error like below:

Response status code does not indicate success: 400 (Bad Request).

Endpoint used :
https://outlook.office365.com/api/v2.0/me/messages?

Code:

Above endpoint is appended with below filter:

"$filter=SingleValueExtendedProperties/any(ep: ep/PropertyId eq 'Binary 0x0fff' and cast (ep/Value, Edm.Binary) eq '" + entryId + "')";

where entryId is 
"00000000224A6557586868FH8N6765SZ6F78768686C9786R7658E8686860886D8768676C8B6CV75V7C57S6F5S8FSF7S9F7D86GD7G57D6G86D84000000"

also tried entryId of below form with no luck:
"AAAAACJKsh5bmbBdknCdkkjAAdjhV76ssn876fBDJg76jdkBfnnnkbslnKns76229873qHGHGnPPSHSFH+gdgf8BmF8aJdgaAAA=="

Please note that I am able to expand properties as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42220623/convert-outlook-rest-api-item-id-to-mapi-entryid), however unable to filter/fetch email with that property. I have followed official documentation at [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/office-365-api/api/version-2.0/extended-properties-rest-operations)

Any help is highly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you want to get the project by filtering the extended properties?
If so, The format of this attribute should be a valid format.
please see the following link:
https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/resources/extended-properties-overview
and
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42220623/convert-outlook-rest-api-item-id-to-mapi-entryid/42228532

Comment: Hi, 

Do you mean filter like below instead ?

"$filter=singleValueExtendedProperties/Any(ep: **ep/id** eq 'Binary 0x0FFF' and **ep/value** eq '" + entryId + "')"

If yes, I have already tried that as well and it did not work. 

Also as I mentioned in my original question post, the method mentioned at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42220623/convert-outlook-rest-api-item-id-to-mapi-entryid/42228532 to expand attributes worked fine for me.

Am I missing anything here?