# Get Office 365 mail id int outlook or web for Graph API

Tags: outlook, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-mail

Where can I found `MessageId` of a mail in Outlook?
I need `Id` to pass it to `Graph API`, so [this](https://www.codetwo.com/kb/messageid/) is not correct id.

It must be something like that:

```
AAE3NzVkZTAwLTNiM2MtNGUwNS1iYzNiLTZjNjM0YTc5985zJhZABGAAAAAABKvyNK5HPTSZZiT7al48txBwC12ftoWcMmSKHMBQzQpO
rDAAAAAAEMAAC12ftoWcMmSKHMBQzQKKJAADRLyVbAAA=
```

I need this for [Graph -> Message](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/message-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Outlook uses the `EntryID` property value for identifying items in the store. To get `EwsId` you must convert it using the following code:

```
string ConvertHexEntryIdToEwsId(ExchangeService esb, string sID, string strSMTPAdd)
{
  AlternateId objAltID = new AlternateId();
  objAltID.Format = IdFormat.HexEntryId;
  objAltID.Mailbox = strSMTPAdd;
  objAltID.UniqueId = sID;

  AlternateIdBase objAltIDBase = esb.ConvertId(objAltID, IdFormat.EwsId);
  AlternateId objAltIDResp = (AlternateId)objAltIDBase;
  return objAltIDResp.UniqueId;
}
```

But I'd suggest using the approach described on the [Convert Outlook REST API item id to MAPI EntryID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42220623/convert-outlook-rest-api-item-id-to-mapi-entryid) page:

> if you wanted to fetch a page of your messages and include the PR_ENTRYID, you could make a GET request to:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages?$expand=singleValueExtendedProperties($filter=id%20eq%20'Binary%200x0FFF')
```